# Pushing to arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm not quite sure why my code is not working here. It is supposed to filter out odd and even numbers and put them into an array but I think my (lack of) understanding is on getting the numbers into the array how I want.

```
function oddAndEven(numbers) {
    var odd = [];
    var even = [];
    for (num = 0; num < numbers.length; numbers++) {
        if (numbers[num] % 2 == 0) {
            even.push(numbers[num]);
        } else if (numbers[num] % 2 == 1) {
            odd.push(numbers[num]);
        }

    }
    console.log(odd + "is odd and " + even + " is even");
}

iqTest(11221122);
```

Comment: `numbers++` ===> `num++`

Comment: See how much easier it is to understand when it's properly indented?

Comment: thank you, I didn't see that. still not pushing numbers into the odd and even arrays though.

Comment: OK, what is "iqTest"? You called the function "oddAndEven". And you're passing a number, yet you expect to be able to look at the "length" property of the value passed to the function. Numbers don't have a length.

Comment: your variable naming is not good. The names `numbers` and `num` can be confusing. Consider using a different name like `index` or simply `i` for running your loop/indexing your array

Comment: You should pass an array to find out even or odd number or if you don't want to pass array that pass number as string then split that string and perform following operation you have been written in above section.

Comment: @pointy that was a mistake during copying the code over. I thought about length however i was not sure what to use to count the numbers in the array. @ sid-m: as far as variable names I read somewhere that using i all the time was a bad habbit but I definately see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function oddAndEven(numbers) {
    var odd = [];
    var even = [];
    for (num = 0; num < numbers.length; num++) { // numbers is array, num is counter variable 
        if (numbers[num] % 2 == 0) {
            even.push(numbers[num]);
        } else if (numbers[num] % 2 == 1) {
            odd.push(numbers[num]);
        }

    }
    console.log(odd + " is odd and " + even + " is even");
}

oddAndEven([10,5,6,4,5]); // pass array as you are traversing though it
```

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing the loop variable was not done in your case. Please try this.

```
function oddAndEven(numbers){
    var odd = [];
    var even = [];
    for(num = 0; num < numbers.length; num++){
        if(numbers[num] % 2 == 0){ //Even
           even.push(numbers[num]);
        }else {                    // Odd
           odd.push(numbers[num]);
        }

    }
    console.log(odd + "is odd and " + even + " is even");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function oddAndEven(numbers) {
var odd = [];
var even = [];
for (num = 0; num < numbers.length; numbers++) {
    if (numbers[num] % 2 == 0) {
        even[num]=numbers[num];
    } else if (numbers[num] % 2 == 1) {
        odd[num]=numbers[num];
    }

}
console.log(odd + "is odd and " + even + " is even");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to improve your practice more.

```
function oddAndEven(numbers) {
    var odd = [];
    var even = [];

    console.log ("length is " , numbers.length);
    for (num = 0; num < numbers.length; num++) {
        if (numbers[num] % 2 == 0) {
            even.push(numbers[num]);
        } else if (numbers[num] % 2 == 1) {
            odd.push(numbers[num]);
        }

    }
    console.log(odd + "is odd and " + even + " is even");
}

oddAndEven("82938411221122919239");
```

You missed num++, and you may want to send the input "82938411221122919239"

As A.T suggested, you shall send [8,2,9,....] as an input also.

Answer (score 0):

```
function oddAndEven(numbers) {
    var odd = [];
    var even = [];
    // a bit of optimization here, accessing `length` property only once
    for (index = numbers.length - 1 ; index >= 0; index--) {
        let current = numbers[index];
        if (current%2 == 0) {
            even.push(current);
        } else {
            odd.push(current);
        }
    }
    console.log(odd + "is odd and " + even + " is even");
}
```